# How to find and replace content of Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to update text in numerous Word files (in a lot of folders and sub folders). I have a function to loop through all of them.

I want to find and replace in the whole document. I can see the files are being opened and closed, but at the end nothing is saved.

```
Sub UpdateOneFolderToUnicode()
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
    strFolder = "my folder here"
    If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub

    'strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal) ' for docx files
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
    While strFile <> ""
        updateOneFile strFolder & "\" & strFile
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
End Sub

Sub updateOneFile(filePath)
    Dim wdDoc As Document
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error GoTo UpdateErr

    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=filePath, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
        With .Range.Find
            .Text = "~"
            .Replacement.Text = ChrW(625)
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .MatchCase = True
        End With
        .Range.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set wdDoc = Nothing    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
    Exit Sub

UpdateErr:
    Debug.Print "Update file: " & filePath & " Error: " & Err.Description
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not getting any errors? If you put a break-point at the `Close` line and look at the document has anything been changed? If you put `wdDoc.Save` in before `wdDoc.Close` does that make a difference? If you change the `Find.Execute` line to `Debug.Print .Range.Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll)` does it put `True` or `False` in the Immediate Window of the VBA Editor?

Answer (score 0):

there is no errors.

and I made it work by updating part of the code to:

```
Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=filePath, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
Set myRange = wdDoc.Content

With myRange.Find
  .Text = "Ä"
  .Replacement.Text = ChrW(256)
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchCase = True
End With
myRange.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Basically use Content instead of Range, and I have to put the wdDoc.Conent into a variable, otherwise still not working (not sure why).